# Unable to find include file on newly updated macOS(C/C++)

Tags: terminal, development, ventura, gcc

I have used the g++ command on the terminal to compile C++ programs but all of a sudden, after an update to my Mac's OS (to macOS 13.3 Ventura,), I started receiving the message:

```
againtest.c:6:10: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
#include <stdio.h>
     ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Then I reinstalled Xcode by `Xcode-select --install` , trying to reset the environment -- nothing works and I reinstalled command line tools and that did not solve the problem that include file is missing.

Later I tried to make it work by:

```
export CPATH='/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platf>
export LIBRARY_PATH='/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOS>
```

My Clion works well but on terminal, it still doesn't work.
If I attempt to compile a simple program like that:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a = 0;
    while(a++ < 10)
        cout << a << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

```
─$ g++ while.cpp 
In file included from while.cpp:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/iostream:41:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/ios:221:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__locale:18:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:841:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__algorithm/copy.h:12:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__algorithm/unwrap_iter.h:13:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__iterator/iterator_traits.h:14:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__iterator/incrementable_traits.h:15:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/concepts:133:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__concepts/arithmetic.h:15:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/type_traits:421:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__functional/invoke.h:15:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__type_traits/apply_cv.h:16:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__type_traits/remove_reference.h:13:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/cstddef:50:9: error: no member named 'nullptr_t' in the global namespace
using ::nullptr_t;
      ~~^
In file included from while.cpp:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/iostream:41:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/ios:221:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__locale:18:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:841:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__algorithm/copy.h:12:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__algorithm/unwrap_iter.h:13:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__iterator/iterator_traits.h:14:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__iterator/incrementable_traits.h:15:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/concepts:133:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__concepts/arithmetic.h:15:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/type_traits:452:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__type_traits/is_compound.h:14:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__type_traits/is_fundamental.h:14:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__type_traits/is_null_pointer.h:24:49: error: use of undeclared identifier 'nullptr_t'
template <>          struct __is_nullptr_t_impl<nullptr_t> : public true_type {};
                                                ^
In file included from while.cpp:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/iostream:41:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/ios:221:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__locale:18:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:848:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/allocator.h:18:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/new:94:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/exception:149:45: error: field has incomplete type 'std::exception_ptr'
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY exception_ptr(nullptr_t) _NOEXCEPT : __ptr_() {}
                                            ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/exception:144:24: note: definition of 'std::exception_ptr' is not complete until the closing '}'
class _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS exception_ptr
                       ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/exception:149:5: error: '__abi_tag__' attribute only applies to structs, variables, functions, and namespaces
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY exception_ptr(nullptr_t) _NOEXCEPT : __ptr_() {}
    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__config:689:37: note: expanded from macro '_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY'
#  define _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY _LIBCPP_HIDE_FROM_ABI
                                    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__config:673:26: note: expanded from macro '_LIBCPP_HIDE_FROM_ABI'
          __attribute__((__abi_tag__(_LIBCPP_TOSTRING(_LIBCPP_VERSIONED_IDENTIFIER))))
                         ^
In file included from while.cpp:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/iostream:41:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/ios:221:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__locale:18:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:848:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/allocator.h:18:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/new:94:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/exception:149:55: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY exception_ptr(nullptr_t) _NOEXCEPT : __ptr_() {}
                                                      ^
In file included from while.cpp:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/iostream:41:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/ios:221:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__locale:18:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:860:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/shared_ptr.h:28:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/unique_ptr.h:173:32: error: member 'nullptr_t' declared as a template
  _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR unique_ptr(nullptr_t) _NOEXCEPT : __ptr_(__value_init_tag(), __value_init_tag()) {}
                               ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/unique_ptr.h:173:42: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
  _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR unique_ptr(nullptr_t) _NOEXCEPT : __ptr_(__value_init_tag(), __value_init_tag()) {}
                                         ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/unique_ptr.h:262:25: error: unknown type name 'nullptr_t'
  unique_ptr& operator=(nullptr_t) _NOEXCEPT {
                        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/unique_ptr.h:395:32: error: member 'nullptr_t' declared as a template
  _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR unique_ptr(nullptr_t) _NOEXCEPT : __ptr_(__value_init_tag(), __value_init_tag()) {}
                               ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/unique_ptr.h:395:42: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
  _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR unique_ptr(nullptr_t) _NOEXCEPT : __ptr_(__value_init_tag(), __value_init_tag()) {}
                                         ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/unique_ptr.h:484:25: error: unknown type name 'nullptr_t'
  unique_ptr& operator=(nullptr_t) _NOEXCEPT {
                        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/unique_ptr.h:533:14: error: unknown type name 'nullptr_t'
  void reset(nullptr_t = nullptr) _NOEXCEPT {
             ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/unique_ptr.h:533:24: error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'int' with an rvalue of type 'std::nullptr_t'
  void reset(nullptr_t = nullptr) _NOEXCEPT {
                       ^ ~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/unique_ptr.h:533:24: note: passing argument to parameter here
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/unique_ptr.h:594:45: error: unknown type name 'nullptr_t'
operator==(const unique_ptr<_T1, _D1>& __x, nullptr_t) _NOEXCEPT
                                            ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/unique_ptr.h:602:12: error: unknown type name 'nullptr_t'
operator==(nullptr_t, const unique_ptr<_T1, _D1>& __x) _NOEXCEPT
           ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/unique_ptr.h:610:45: error: unknown type name 'nullptr_t'
operator!=(const unique_ptr<_T1, _D1>& __x, nullptr_t) _NOEXCEPT
                                            ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/unique_ptr.h:618:12: error: unknown type name 'nullptr_t'
operator!=(nullptr_t, const unique_ptr<_T1, _D1>& __x) _NOEXCEPT
           ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/unique_ptr.h:626:44: error: unknown type name 'nullptr_t'
operator<(const unique_ptr<_T1, _D1>& __x, nullptr_t)
                                           ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/unique_ptr.h:635:11: error: unknown type name 'nullptr_t'
operator<(nullptr_t, const unique_ptr<_T1, _D1>& __x)
          ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
```

Would like some help on this.

Comment: fwiw: similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75921280/updating-to-macos-13-3-broke-compiling-cpp

Comment: Just asked about this in the developer forums as well: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/729072

Answer (score 2):

We have the same issue and fixed with this:

- Run Xcode.app
- Delete SDK 13.3 and use 12.3 instead
- Do `xcode-select --install` and continue to work on your project

Comment: I'm so glad to hear that downgrading allows you to continue working!  This bug has stopped my own development in its tracks.  Unf. if you're trying to target the latest versions of Ventura (macos 13.3) using SDK 13.3 seems to the only way (per guidelines on this page:  https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/ )  I'm crossing my fingers for a real fix from Apple (and have submitted the issue via the Feedback Reporter tool) but grateful for the workaround you found!

Comment: also, see my answer below for how I solved the issue

Answer (score 2):

I was having this issue and finally tracked it down to an environment variable that was set in my environment.

The variable is

```
CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH
```

I had previously followed the workaround described [here](https://cmichel.io/fixing-cpp-compilation-bugs-for-the-mac-os-catalina-upgrade/) which involved setting an environment variable (in my bash .profile) :

```
CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/opt/llvm/include/c++/v1:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include
```

**Removing the CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH environment variable fixed the problem and compilation works again.**

Hopefully this will help someone else get past this tricky/subtle build problem!

If not, "eskimo" on the Apple Developer forums offered some helpful diagnostic suggestions when I posted this issue [on the Apple Developer Forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/729072).  Maybe those would be of use.

The diagnostic commands he requested I run were the following :

- `sw_vers`
- `xcode-select -p` (to show setting)
- `xcode-select -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` (to set setting)
- `csrutil status`
- `pkgutil --pkgs`
- `printenv | \grep CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` (my own addition)

The results of these commands might be helpful for someone to help you, if you continue to have problems.

Comment: Apple Developers forums are available to everybody, registered or not.

Comment: @Thinkr Thank you for the info and thoughtful edits!

Answer (score 2):

**MacOS Ventura 13.5**
Found and tried many different solutions for multiple hours. NO need to `update brew`, (re)install `gcc`, (re)install `XCode`, run `xcode-select --install`, or edit the `Makevars` file.

What helped was removing the problematic directory from the Terminal

```
cd /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs
rm -rf MacOSX.sdk
```

If you are unsure, you can rename the directory, instead of deleting it

```
cd /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs
sudo mv MacOSX.sdk MacOSX_old.sdk
```

However, running the `ln -s` suggested above did not help!

Comment: You are right, I am on Ventura M2. Running `rm -rf MacOSX.sdk` is enough. If one already link the file with `ln -s MacOSX13.3.sdk MacOSX.sdk` or something like that, just unlink it with `rm -rf MacOSX.sdk` again and it is good to go.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I did not have xcode install, so I followed the path to commandlinetools/sdks and created a new link to 12.3 sdk to make it work:

```
cd /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
rm -rf MacOSX.sdk
ln -s MacOSX12.3.sdk MacOSX.sdk
```

Dont need to run `xcode-select --install`

Hope it helps!

Comment: Man, you are a lifesaver. It works, but in my case, except to `rm -rf MacOSX.sdk`, I had to call also `rm -rf MacOSX13.3.sdk`.

Comment: I'm so glad to hear that downgrading allows you to continue working! This bug has stopped my own development in its tracks. Unf. if you're trying to target the latest versions of Ventura (macos 13.3) using SDK 13.3 seems to the only way (per guidelines on this page: https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode ) I'm crossing my fingers for a real fix from Apple (and have submitted the issue via the Feedback Reporter tool) but grateful for the workaround you found! See my own answer here for how I was able to get around this and continue with the latest and 'greatest' sdk